# What would be the appropriate database model for post, img-thumbnail and file?

Tags: database, postgresql, join, typeorm, modeling

I'm trying to design a database model using postgresql.

### *Requirements

There are two or three kinds of thumbnails for Post (e.g. thumbnail_sm, thumgnail_md).

The list of posts appear on the landing page with their thumbnails.

Also, users can download a file of a post on the same list page.

The list page may show around between 10 to 25 posts per a single page.

Option.#1
[image]

Option.#2

[image]

If I choose to go with three entities: Post, Photo, and File,

would there be too much joins for the list page?

Should I just put urls on the Post entity?

I'm a newbie for Backend.

I'm not sure which way is better for performance as well as scalability.

My question is "What would be the best approach for the database model in this case?"

Comment: Your option 2 suggests that there can be only one thumbnail per post. I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the thumbnails images are not reused (shared) by different posts, then there is no reason to normalize the schema. Go with #2 and make sure you change it to accommodate all 3 thumbnails by adding the missing columns. Also, is gonna be faster for retrieving data as there are no joins.